# Onesignal Expo SDK Setup Google Android FCM Configuration, cannot read property 'smallIcons' of undefined at withSmallIcons (\withOneSignalAndroid.js)

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I'm using Onesignal for push notifications but am stuck in an error and could not find the solution for many days.

**OneSignal SDK Configuration:**

1. I configured the Google Android (FCM) Configuration with Firebase Server Key and  Firebase Sender ID at Onesignal and selected the React Native/Expo SDK and copied the APP ID.

**Expo SDK Setup:**

1. I have Expo Managed Workflow so I run the command

> expo install onesignal-expo-plugin

2. then I executed the command

> yarn add react-native-onesignal

3. Added the below code into App.json

> {   "plugins": [
> "onesignal-expo-plugin",
> {
> "mode": "development",
> }] }

4. After that import react-native-onesignal and used APP ID in useEffect into reuqired JS

> import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';

> useEffect(() => {
> OneSignal.setAppId("Pasted Copied APP ID here");   }, []);

5. After that Run the Command

> expo prebuild

but getting error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'smallIcons' of undefinedn at withSmallIcons (\node_modules\onesignal-expo-plugin\build\onesignal\withOneSignalAndroid.js)
```

now getting this error on all console commands related to this react-native project.

I configured Onesignal through the below documentation
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-expo-sdk-setup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it.
actually, the error was occurring in the below code

```
"plugins": [
        "onesignal-expo-plugin",
        {
          "mode": "development"
        }
    ]
```

adding the extra Square brackets [  ] solved the "Cannot read property 'smallIcons' of undefined" problem

```
"plugins": [
      [
        "onesignal-expo-plugin",
        {
          "mode": "development"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: That’s weird because that code is added automatically with only one pair of brackets.
Thank you for the solution!